# Garden doesnt find services to deploy

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a sample react project that is created with create-react-app to kubernetes using [garden](https://docs.garden.io/), however, no services can be found. As in the [example](https://github.com/garden-io/garden/tree/master/examples/demo-project), I have created a `project.garden.yml` in the root folder. In the React project's folder, I've created the `garden.yml`.

```
kind: Project
name: react-app
environments:
    name: default
providers:
    name: local-kubernetes
    environments: [default]
```

Above is `project.garden.yml` that is in the *root folder*.

```
kind: Module
type: container
name: reactapp
dockerfile: Dockerfile
services:
  name: reactapp
  args:
    - yarn
    - start
  ingresses:
    - path: /api
      port: http
```

Above is the `garden.yml` which is the root folder of the react *module*.

When I enter the command `garden deploy` or `garden deploy --force-refresh`, it outputs the following:

```
Deploy  

✔ providers                 → Getting status... → Done
No services to deploy. Aborting.
```

React's `Dockerfile` is like following:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

What am I missing here so that project finds the react module and deploys it onto the local kubernetes which is running on Docker.

Comment: Your service definition is a map in the example above but it should be an array. However, in that case the schema validation should fail and you should see a different error. I can't see anything else wrong with the config at a glance. Are you still having this issue?j